# Change Default Drupal password hashing function

Tags: php, security, drupal-7

I am migrating a site from a custom java platform to drupal 7 and I want the users to be able to login to the new platform using the same credentials. The java platform encrypts the password using java

> java.security.MessageDigest

with SHA256. Is  it possible to override the default drupal encryption function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the variable "password_inc" which is the include for password hashing. In this file you can include a "user_check_password" function which checks the password with your custom encryption / hashing function.